# Structural (causal) interpretation of the completeness condition

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, complete-statistics

Consider two random variables $X,Y$. We say the joint distribution of $P(X,Y)$ is [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(statistics)) w.r.t. $X$ if the following condition holds:

> For all $y$, $E\{g(x)|y\}=0$ almost everywhere if and only $g(x)=0$ almost everywhere.

A [structural causal model](https://medium.data4sci.com/causal-inference-part-iv-structural-causal-models-df10a83be580?gi=fe69e9791975) (scm) over $(X,Y)$ is:

> $X \leftarrow f(Y,U)$, where $f$ is the structual function and $U$ is the exogenous variable.

My question is: under what conditions (over $f,U$, and possibly $P(Y)$) is the joint distribution $P(X,Y$) entailed by the scm $X\leftarrow f(Y,U)$ complete w.r.t. $X$?

I did some searching but found no straight answer. Some of my conjectures:

- $f$ is an injective function.
- $Y$, $U$ both follow distribution families that are complete themselves.

Comment: I found a paper showing that completeness is satisfied by addictive noise model (ANM)  if and only if the characteristic function of $U$ is strictly positive everywhere.  Reference: Lemma 2.2, Hu & Shiu (2021). A simple test of completeness in a class of nonparametric specification.